# Convert integer number to three digit

Tags: c#, asp.net, integer, digits

I have an integer variable .if its 1-9 it only displays as "1" or "9", I'm looking to convert the variable to save as 3 digits, ie. "001", or "009", etc. any ideas?
I am using C#,ASP.Net

Comment: What are you looking to convert it with?

Comment: You should use 'String' to store something like '001'

Answer (score 30, accepted):

use

```
int X = 9;

string PaddedResult = X.ToString().PadLeft (3, '0'); // results in 009
```

see MSDN references [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830.aspx).

Comment: I prefer the readability of the format string but if you're doing it lots, I suspect this will be faster right?

Comment: @LexyStardust it might be faster but I like it because the length of the string can be a variable (first parameter in the call to Pad...) which in turn makes it rather easy to configure...

Comment: Sorry I meant that this solution would be faster - won't be all the funky lookups to FormatProviders that goes underneath Format().

Answer (score 20):

What about

```
var result = String.Format("{0:000}", X);
var result2 = X.ToString("000");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int i = 5;
string tVal=i.ToString("000");
```

Answer (score 3):

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#DFormatString

The "D" (or decimal) format specifier converts a number to a string of decimal digits (0-9), prefixed by a minus sign if the number is negative.

The precision specifier indicates the minimum number of digits desired in the resulting string. If required, the number is padded with zeros to its left to produce the number of digits given by the precision specifier.

Like:

```
int value; 

value = 12345;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("D"));
// Displays 12345
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("D8"));
// Displays 00012345

value = -12345;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("D"));
// Displays -12345
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("D8"));
// Displays -00012345
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 5;
string retVal = i.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code also

```
int k = 5;
string name =  $"name-{k++:D3}.ext";
```